# Equation $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$ (mod $p$)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to prove that equation $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$ (mod $p$) has roots?

Hints are acceptable.

Comment: Hint: If you take $y=0$, then all $p$ with $(\frac{-1}{p})=1$ are solved.

Comment: You can show that for $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, $y=0, x=\pm\sqrt{-1}$ is a solution where $\sqrt{-1}$ exists because of the requirement $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$...

Comment: Hint: Every element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a sum of two squares in that ring.

Comment: You can directly write the solution of the equation: $x^2+y^2=pz-1$  It's easier.

Comment: @vadim123 okay, but if $(\frac{-1}{p}) = -1$ then what?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson it seems pretty equal to the whole statement.

Comment: @Jihad: It is essentially equivalent, I agree, but it is not so hard to prove directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Note that $x^2$ takes on $\frac{p+1}{2}$ distinct values modulo $p$, and so does $-(y^2+1)$. Now use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: How about if we impose $x,y\neq 0$? See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564213/163930).

Comment: Why does $x^{2}$ take on $\frac{p+1}{2}$ distinct values modulo $p$?