# Using the Sum of Two Squares theorem and Dirichlet Theorem to solve $x^2 + y^2 = k$ for $x,y,k\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^*$.

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof

Some days ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564213/for-which-primes-p-is-1-not-the-sum-of-two-non-zero-quadratic-residues) and managed to come up with an answer that determines the existence of a solution to the equation

$$x^2 + y^2 = k$$

where $x,y$ are non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, such solution exists for all $p>5$ and $k\neq 0$.

---

What I ask here is to find what the following alternative argument needs for it to be a complete one.

The Sum of Two Squares Theorem tells us that all the primes of the form $4r+1$ can be expressed as the sum of two perfect squares.

So if we find a prime $q$ of the form $4r+1$ such that $q\equiv k \pmod p$ then there are integers $X$ and $Y$ such that $X^2 + Y^2 = q$ and if $x,y$ are the remainders of $X$ and $Y$ modulo $p$, respectively, then $x^2 + y^2 \equiv k \pmod p$.

Now this would be a solution to our original problem as long as $p$ doesn't divide $X$ nor $Y$.

Such prime is always guaranteed to exist due to Dirichlet's Theorem. Indeed, we need to find a prime $q$ such that

$$q\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\ q \equiv k \pmod p.$$

For $p\neq 2$ then $4$ and $p$ are coprime and therefore there are integers $m,n$ such that

$$4m + pn = 1$$
due to Bézout's Identity. Note that this implies that $(m,p) = (n,4) = 1$. So any prime of the form

$$pn + 4mk + 4pt$$
for some natural number $t$ would solve the above congruences. Since $(4p, pn+4mk) = 1$ then Dirichlet's Theorem assures us that there are infinitely many primes of that form.

Now, if $k$ happens to be a quadratic non-residue then we can take any prime $q$ of that form, find the corresponding $X$ and $Y$ and project them onto $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a nice solution because we are guaranteed that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero.

However, we need some additional argument to prove that some primes will yield a solution where $p$ doesn't divide $X$ nor $Y$. This argument would have to fail for $p = 5$ since no such solutions exist for that case, but should succeed for any prime $p > 5$.

Comment: A couple of clarifications: $k\not\equiv 0 \operatorname{mod} p$? Also, your question is about finding $X$ and $Y$ when $k$ _is_ a quadratic residue $\operatorname{mod} p$?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 the question is about proving the existence of a prime $q$ for which the corresponding $X$ and $Y$ are not congruent to $0$ $\pmod p$ even if $k$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$. And yes, for our purposes $k \neq 0$.

Comment: Well if $p$ is congruent to $1$ or $7$ mod $8$, then $2$ is a quadratic residue $\operatorname{mod} p$. So $2$'s inverse $\operatorname{mod} p$, $v$, is also congruent to some square, $w^2$, $\operatorname{mod} p$. So, if $k$ is a quadratic residue $\equiv j^2 \operatorname{mod} p$, $k\equiv (2v)k\equiv 2(w^2j^2)\equiv (wj)^2+(wj)^2\operatorname{mod} p$. Clearly $wj\not\equiv 0\operatorname{mod} p$. So at least this special case of $p$ is satisfied for arbitrary $k$ (I think).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and answer in a way that simplifies the steps in the result as much as possible. But I'll start with one statement as given: that the Legendre symbol is completely multiplicative, i.e. a product of a residue and a nonresidue is a nonresidue, etc.

**Fact:** Let $p$ be any prime $>5$. Then, there exists at least one pair of consecutive residues $\operatorname{mod} p$.

The proof below was borrowed from [the answer at the bottom here, by Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292747/631681). His second answer on that page, where he shows to derive an explicit formula for the number of consecutive residue pairs may also provide some insight.

*Proof*: Since $p$ is a prime $>5$, $2$ and $5$ are nonzero elements $\operatorname{mod} p$. If either $2$ or $5$ is a residue $\operatorname{mod} p$, we are done, because then one of $(1,2)=(1^2,2)$ and $(4,5)=(2^2,5)$ will be our desired pair of consecutive residues. If both $2$ and $5$ are nonresidues, then, since the Legendre symbol is multiplicative, $10=2\cdot 5$ will be a residue $\operatorname{mod} p$. But in that case, $(9,10)=(3^2,10)$ will be a consecutive residue pair. So we are done.

Ok, so we have the existence of consecutive residues $\operatorname{mod} p$. How does that help with the problem at hand?

So, say we're given some prime $p$ that's $>5$. We know that there'll exist some residues of the form $w$ and $w+1$. Since $w$ is a residue, $w\equiv z^2\operatorname{mod} p$ for some nonzero $z$. But this means $w+1\equiv z^2+1^2\operatorname{mod} p$ and $w+1$ is a residue. So at the very least one residue, $w+1$, can be expressed, via congruence, as the sum of two nonzero squares.

How can we relate this to the expression of our arbitrary residue, $k$, as a sum of two squares? Notice that, since $k$ and $w+1$ are both residues, $k$ and $(w+1)^{-1}$ are a pair of residues ($(w+1)^{-1}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $w+1\operatorname{mod} p$). Then (by the property of the Legendre symbol) $k(w+1)^{-1}$ is a residue $\operatorname{mod} p$, i.e. it is congruent to some $j^2$ (for some nonzero $j$). This gives us $k\equiv j^2(w+1)\operatorname{mod} p$.

Then, by the facts already shown, we have $k\equiv (jz)^2+j^2 \operatorname{mod} p$ making it possible to represent $k$ as the sum of $2$ nonzero squares $\operatorname{mod} p$.

At this point, we are done. If you observe carefully what we have done above, you'll notice that, fixing $j$, we can convert any expression for $k$ as a sum of two squares to an expression of $w+1$ as a sum of two squares and vice versa. That $w+1$ is part of a consecutive pair of residues is irrelevant to this fact. It is also clear, by the Legendre property, that the same would hold if we replace both $k$ and $w+1$ by a pair of nonresidues. Lastly, it is independent of the exact value of $p$ (whether or not it be $>$ or $\leq 5$). This brings us to a bonus fact:

**Bonus Fact:** If $p$ is any prime and $x$ and $y$ are any pair of residues or nonresidues $\operatorname{mod} p$, the number of pairs $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$ for which $a^2+b^2\equiv x$ is equal to the number of pairs $(c,d)\in \mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$ for which $c^2+d^2\equiv y$.

This can be used in some counting arguments regarding the number of representations of numbers as sums of two squares $\operatorname{mod}$ a prime.

**EDIT**: As for the use of Dirichlet's theorem in this problem. Its (direct) use is only in proving the existence of a sum-of-squares decomposition for nonresidues (as such a decomposition trivially exists for any residue).  For nonresidues, [the accepted answer under this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891861/sum-of-two-squares-modulo-p) does the job quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

One shouldn't work too hard here. First, if there is a square root of $-1$ in the finite field, $x^2+y^2$ factors and there are non-trivial solutions. If there is *no* square root of $-1$ in the finite field, then there is one in the unique quadratic extension. By Lagrange's theorem, the Galois norm from $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ to $\mathbb F_p$ is surjective, so, again, the equation has solutions...